# Bootstrap Modal Pop Up bind controls - Dropdownlist

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have an HTML table which loads data from the database. When I click on a row a modal pop fetches more content from the database with an option to edit a change on the selected row.

My predicament is how do I populate a drop-down list and select a value saved in the database?

It is easy to bind other controls i.e. Textarea, input boxes etc. My issue is with dropdown lists.

FYI I'm using ASP.NET Web Forms with C# and I fetch the data from the database using jQuery AJAX and a WebService.
Thanx in advance.

I have mixed the presentation with the logic.
I have updated the question here is the js:

```
 $("body").delegate("a.view-link", "click", function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var requestID = $(this).data("reqid"); 
    $.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "../helpdeskservice.asmx/GetModalContent", 
    data: "{'requestID':'" + requestID + "'}", 
    contentType: "application/json; 
    charset=utf-8", 
    dataType: "json", 
   success: function (response) {
     $('#modalEditCall').html(response.d); //Bind 
     $('#requestConfirmed').modal('toggle') } });
    $('#modalEditCall').modal('toggle') 
});
```

The WebService Method

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string GetModalContent(string requestID)
    {
        try
        {
            return ViewExtensions.GetCallModal(requestID);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

The C# Class I use to build the html

```
     public static string GetCallModal(string requestID)
     {
        var usrRequestObject = new DBHelpDesk();
        var categories = usrRequestObject.GetCategories();
        var modalddlCategories = new StringBuilder(String.Empty);

        modalddlCategories.Append(@"<select class='custom-select w-100' id='modalddlCategory' required>");

        foreach (var category in categories)
        {
            modalddlCategories.AppendFormat(@"<option value='{0}'>{1}</option>",category.CategoryID,category.Description);
        }
        modalddlCategories.Append("</select>");

        var sb = new StringBuilder(String.Empty);

        var userRequest = DBHelpDesk.GetCallByID(requestID);

        sb.AppendFormat(@"
                        <div class='modal-dialog' role='document'>
                            <div class='modal-content'>
                                <div class='modal-header'>
                                    <h5 class='modal-title'>{0}</h5>
                                    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'>
                                        <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class='modal-body'>
                                    <div class='row'>
                                        <div class='col-md-6 mb-3'>
                                            <label for='txtDescription'>Description</label>
                                                <input type='text' class='form-control' id='txtmodalDescription' placeholder='' value='' required>
                                            <div class='invalid-feedback'>
                                              Valid first name is required.
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='row'>
                                    <div class='col-md-6 mb-3'>
                                        <label for='state'>Category</label>
                                        {1}
                                        <div class='invalid-feedback'>
                                            Please provide a valid state.
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='col-md-6 mb-3'>
                                        <label for='state'>Sub-Category</label>
                                        <select class='custom-select w-100' id='modalddlSubCategory' required>
                                        </select>
                                        <div class='invalid-feedback'>
                                            Please provide a valid state.
                                        </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='row'>
                                        <div class='col-md-6 mb-3'>
                                            <label for='state'>Status</label>
                                            <select class='custom-select w-100' id='modalddlStatus' required>
                                                <option value='0'>Open</option>
                                                <option value='1'>In-Progress</option>
                                                <option value='2'>Awaiting Reply</option>
                                                <option value='3'>Closed</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <div class='invalid-feedback'>
                                                Please provide a valid state.
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class='col-md-6 mb-3'>
                                            <label for='state'>Request Mode</label>
                                            <select class='custom-select w-100' id='modalddlRequest' required>
                                                <option value='0'>Low</option>
                                                <option value='1'>Medium</option>
                                                <option value='2'>High</option>
                                                <option value='3'>Critical</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <div class='invalid-feedback'>
                                                Please provide a valid state.
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='row'>
                                        <div class='col-md-12 mb-3'>
                                            <label for='cc-name'>Comments</label>
                                            <textarea id='txtmodalEditor' class='form-control'>{3}</textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            <div class='modal-footer'>
                                <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>Update Call</button>
                                <button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      ", DBHelpDesk.GetUserFullName(userRequest.UserID)
                       , modalddlCategories
                       , userRequest.Description
                       , userRequest.Comments);

        return sb.ToString();
    }

  <div>
    <div class="row">
        <nav class="col-md-2 d-none d-md-block bg-light sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-sticky">
                <ul class="nav flex-column">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">
                            <span data-feather="home"></span>
                            Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="../new/request.aspx">
                            <span data-feather="file"></span>
                            New Request
            </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                            <span data-feather="shopping-cart"></span>
                            Products
            </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                            <span data-feather="users"></span>
                            Customers
            </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                            <span data-feather="bar-chart-2"></span>
                            Reports
            </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                            <span data-feather="layers"></span>
                            Integrations
            </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <h6 class="sidebar-heading d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center px-3 mt-4 mb-1 text-muted">
                    <span>Reports</span>
                    <a class="d-flex align-items-center text-muted" href="#">
                        <span data-feather="plus-circle"></span>
                    </a>
                </h6>
                <ul class="nav flex-column mb-2">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                            <span data-feather="file-text"></span>
                            Current month
            </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                            <span data-feather="file-text"></span>
                            Last quarter
            </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 pt-3 px-4">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
                <h1 class="h2">Dashboard</h1>
                <div class="btn-toolbar mb-2 mb-md-0">
                    <div class="btn-group mr-2">
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Share</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Export</button>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle">
                        <span data-feather="calendar"></span>
                        This week

                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <canvas class="my-4" id="myChart" width="900" height="380"></canvas>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9 mb-3">
                    <h2>CALL LOG SHEET</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                    <select class="form-control float-right">
                        <option>Open</option>
                        <option>Closed</option>
                        <option>All</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <asp:Literal ID="lblContent" runat="server"></asp:Literal>

        </main>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="modalEditCall" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <asp:Literal ID="lblModalContent" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</div>
```

Here is the dropdown list

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4aUa.gif)

Comment: can you share the code

Comment: This is the C# code

Comment: I can't see the see code @Thabo

Comment: where is dropdownlist html .. please share the HTML, C# too.

Comment: I have updated the question with all the code.